# how to divide two rows

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have a table

| date | measure | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-09 | A | 10 |
| 2022-12-09 | B | 2 |
| 2022-12-03 | A | 300 |
| 2022-12-03 | B | 30 |

i need to have new rows C=A/B

| date | measure | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-09 | A | 10 |
| 2022-12-09 | B | 2 |
| 2022-12-09 | C | 5 |
| 2022-12-03 | A | 300 |
| 2022-12-03 | B | 30 |
| 2022-12-03 | C | 10 |

how it can be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using conditional aggregation along with a union we can try:

```sql
SELECT date, measure, value FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT
    date,
    'C',
    MAX(CASE WHEN measure = 'A' THEN value END) /
    MAX(CASE WHEN measure = 'B' THEN value END)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date, measure;
```